# Change a video that plays in a VideoView whenever I want. Manually

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I have an activity that has a button, when I click this button another activity opens and plays a video defined by me from sdcard (or phone).

The problem: I want to change which video will play always when I wish.

Example: first I pre-define to play a video about Mario. Later, I want that the same button plays a video about Luigi, then I do some method that allow me to make this trade. Or any user that use the app.

Anybody could help me how can I do this?

Here's the basic code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    

    video_player = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_frame); 
    media_Controller = new MediaController(this);
    dm = new DisplayMetrics(); 
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int height = dm.heightPixels; 
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    video_player.setMinimumWidth(width); 
    video_player.setMinimumHeight(height); 
    video_player.setMediaController(media_Controller); 
    video_player.setVideoPath("/sdcard/videoplay.mp4"); 
    video_player.start(); 

}
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: i edited @NguyễnHoàiNam  Its a simple code. But i dont want to play this video in sdcard. I want to change everytime, by clicking some kind of button in the activity. I dont know if you understood me

Comment: How about change this line to what ever Video URL you want ```video_player.setVideoPath("/sdcard/videoplay.mp4");```. Furthermore, please read about setOnPreparedListener() which is a better place for you to call ```video_player.start()``` (You got the idea from the name I hope)

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam sorry, i don't understand what you mean :/

Answer (score 1):

In button click dynamatically change video url as per your wish store string url. 
//first activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VideoFullScreenActivity.class);       
    intent.putExtra("URL", url);
    startActivity(intent);
```

//video activity

```
if (intent.hasExtra("URL")) {
            urlVideo = intent.getStringExtra("URL");
        }

        video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        media = new CustomMediaController(this);
        media.setAnchorView(video);
        video.setMediaController(media);

    video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlVideo));
    video.requestFocus();
    video.seekTo(current);

    video.start();
```

Comment: But how i change video to play always in that button choosing from gallery, and make this video default

Comment: set button click  Intent intent = new Intent();
          
intent.setType("video/*");
          intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

          startActivityForResult(Intent
            .createChooser(intent,
              "Select Picture"),1);

Comment: In onActivityResult you get path of video. and pass that path in URL.